# Tensorflow: Failed to parse supervisedKeys field: Message type "tensorflow_datasets.SupervisedKeys"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am required to use `python 3.8` and `tensorflow 2.7.0` and `tensorflow_datasets: 4.4.0` for the Tensorflow certification exam and i am trying to work with `mnist` dataset using the following code :

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Load dataset
(train_data, test_data), ds_info = tfds.load(name='mnist',  # Dataset name
                                             split=["train", "test"],  # which split is going to be taken
                                             shuffle_files=True,
                                             as_supervised=True,  # get labels of data (feature,label)
                                             with_info=True)  # include dataset meta-data
```

However, when i run the code, i face with the following error:

```
google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to construct dataset mnist: Failed to parse supervisedKeys field: Message type "tensorflow_datasets.SupervisedKeys" has no field named "tuple".
 Available Fields(except extensions): ['input', 'output'].
```

What is the reason and how i can fix it ?

---

Update: When i run it on google-colab it works well, however on my local machine the error happening. I am preparing the configuration of my laptop for the Tensorflow certification exam and that;s why i am requeired to use the following configs and i cannot change it:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sal-laS, I tried the same in Pycharm with your mentioned configuration settings for TF certification by creating virtual environment and found no error while running above code. Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf) document to verify your system settings and try again executing the above code. Let us know if issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you may not need to know the answer to this now (1 year and 4 months later) but I ran into a similar problem.  My fix was to change the version of the protobuf in the PyCharm virtual environment interpreter.  After you install the tensorflow version == 2.9.0 you need to then search "protobuf" and set it to version "3.20.1".  That solved my issue.  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: A little more explanation for anyone running into this problem...  When you install the stated version of tensorflow detailed in the [TensorFlow Candidate Handbook](https://www.tensorflow.org/static/extras/cert/TF_Certificate_Candidate_Handbook.pdf) and the [TF Exam Env Setup](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf), it still installs the most up-to-date version of `protofub` (which is not compatible).  Therefore _after_ you install `tensorflow` you have to roll back `protobuf` to a compatible version.